# How to generate custom control sets for Smac State Lattice Planner?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-smac-planner.html

Link shows " *See the Smac Planner package to generate custom control sets for your vehicle* ". But was not able to find how to generate custom json file (lattice_filepath argument in *plugin nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerLattice*).

Any leads will be helpful!

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393347/how-to-generate-custom-control-sets-for-smac-state-lattice-planner?/) by [jainr](https://answers.ros.org/users/92132/jainr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2021-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is something described about the control sets:

[link text](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_smac_planner/lattice_primitives)

But I also haven't really understand how to make properly own, custom ones. I tried (manually) define the output.json file, but with unsuccessful results (at least the Planner didn't behave as I expected)

---

Originally posted by [ahopsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/75387/ahopsu/) with karma: 83 on 2022-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on 2022-12-22**:
I am facing a problem for tunning a differential/rectangular robot, did anyone of you figure out how to customize it ? [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/410769/smac-lattice-planner-for-differential-robot/) is my question